# how to remove error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token?

Tags: c, data-structures

[program picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8QXZ.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree {
    int data;
    struct tree *left, *right;
};

struct queue {
    struct tree **nodeQ = (struct tree**)malloc(sizeof(struct tree*));
    int front;
    int rear;
};
```

Comment: Start with understanding you can't do that in C.

Comment: --> `struct tree **    nodeQ;`

Answer (score 1):

In C you can't initialize structure members inline like you try to do with the `nodeQ` member.

You need to initialize the member when you create the structure.

So you need to do something like

```
struct queue q = { malloc(sizeof(struct tree *)), 0, 0 };
```

or

```
struct queue *q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
q->nodeQ = malloc(sizeof(struct tree *));
q->front = 0;
q->rear = 0;
```

<sub>Note that I [do not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is initializing the structure when you define it.
When using struct name_of_struct{...}; You are defining a data type. Due to this you can't give it an inicial value.

```
struct tree{

     int data;        
     struct tree *left,*right;    

};       


struct queue{

    struct tree ** nodeQ;  
    int front;    
    int rear;    

};
```

This should do as a definition, also remember to use indentation and comment your code as this will result in a much more understandable program and you'll actually understand it 2 weeks from now.

Also I think there's actually an error in your code, shouldn't nodeQ be a normal pointer and not a double pointer? If you try to dereference(acess the content referenced by the pointer) twice you'll get a seg fault.

Here's how you should initialize the content of nodeQ supposing its a SINGLE POINTER and in a function I'll initialize it in the main function this time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    




struct tree{

    int data;        
    struct tree *left,*right;    

};       


struct queue{

    struct tree * nodeQ;
    int front;    
    int rear;    

}; 



int main(void)
{
    struct queue my_queue;
    if(my_queue.nodeQ=malloc(sizeof(struct tree)))
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for my_queue nodeQ\n");


    return 0;
}
```